# Calling R script from Python using subprocess and passing variable (floating type)

Tags: r, python-3.x, subprocess

I am new to python.

I have a task where I need to call R from python and I need to pass a number as a variable to the R script. Below is what I am doing

```
import subprocess
i = 1
r_call = "/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/Rscript"
path2script = "/home/python/calculate.R"
cmd =  [r_call,path2script] + i
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=False)
```

This is isnt working. Any idea what is the right way to do it? Below is a test R script I created to check if the variable is getting passed

```
P <- args[1]
interest <- 1 - P
interest
```

Comment: I think ```i``` needs to be passed inside the ```[r_call,path2script]``` command list

Comment: how can I pass it within that?

Comment: Try `cmd = [r_call, path2script, str(i)]`